generalized poisson moment function approach to initalize input output model
I am trying to understand how the Generalized Poisson Moment Functions apporach is a way to initalize the nominator and denominaor of a LTI-Model that describes the connection between Input and Output Data. I understand modeling and systems very well and the Generalized Poisson Moments to some extend. I just cant seem to find any good literature that connects the two. Do you have any advice for literature or explanation what exactly happens there? To be precise: I am talking about the "InitalizeMethod" gpmf from tfest (Matlab)
Best regards

You might want to use the book-recommendation tag.
